# Replace images with the fa-awesome icons in ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

For Example I have an imageButton like,

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="controlId" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Img1.gif"
 AlternateText="alt" meta:resourcekey="resource" />
```

And for the functionality of toggle I have,

```
<ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpeShowUsers" runat="server" TargetControlID="plCollapse"
                            ExpandControlID="plCollapseHead" CollapseControlID="plCollapseHead" Collapsed="true"
                            TextLabelID="lblShowUsr" ImageControlID="controlId" 
                            ExpandedImage="~/Img1.gif"
                            CollapsedImage="~/Img2.gif" SuppressPostBack="True" />
```

Which basically gives me the toggle functionality using images but I am trying to mimic the same functionality using fa-awesome icons to optimize the performance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made use of ExpandedText and CollapsedText to insert the Font Awesome Icons and it's working now.

```
 <asp:Label ID="Show" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-lg" style="color:blue;"></i></asp:Label>

 <ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpeShowUsers" runat="server" TargetControlID="plCollapse"
 ExpandControlID="plCollapseHead" CollapseControlID="plCollapseHead" Collapsed="true"
 TextLabelID="Show" CollapsedText="<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-lg' style='color:blue;'></i>"
 ExpandedText="<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-lg' style='color:blue;'></i>"  SuppressPostBack="True" />
```